# React Native Navigation navigator reset view position

Tags: android, ios, react-native, react-navigation

I have a nested React Native Navigation set up where at the top level I have a TabNavigator and each `screen` in the TabNavigator is a StackNavigator.

When I switch between tabs I noticed that if I have a ScrollView in one of the StackNavigators that it's position remains. This is fine for some screens (e.g. a feed) but for other screens it should reset the position of the screen after having navigated away (or just before navigating) to that screen.

How can I reset the position of a ScrollView in a nested React Native Navigation navigator?

Comment: Android or iOS? Or both?

Comment: @Slava Both platforms.